# How do I substitute with an evaluated expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

There's a file dummy.txt

The contents are:

```
 9/0/2010
 9/2/2010
 10/11/2010
```

I have to change the month portion (0,2,11) to +1, ie, (1,3,12)
I wrote the substitution regex as follows

```
 $line =~ s/\/(\d+)\//\/\1+1\//;
```

It's is printing

```
9/0+1/2010
9/2+1/2010
10/11+1/2010
```

How to make it add - `3` numerically than perform string concat? `2+1`??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Three changes:

- You'll have to use the `e` modifier
  to allow an expression in the
  replacement part.
- To make the replacement globally
  you should use the `g` modifier. This is *not* needed if you've one date per line.
- You use `$1` on the replacement side, not a backreference

This should work:

```
$line =~ s{/(\d+)/}{'/'.($1+1).'/'}eg;
```

Also if your regex contains the delimiter you're using(`/` in your case), it's better to choose a different delimiter (`{}` above), this way you don't have to escape the delimiter in the regex making your regex clean.

Comment: awesome!, it worked - if you don't mind can you explain the s{} syntax - I mean is it possible to achieve it with s/ rather than s{

Comment: @OP: I've updated my answer. `s///` is equivalent to `s{}{}`, just that it uses a different delimiter and will save you from escaping those `/`.

Comment: While not required, using the 'x' modifier to your regular expressions greatly enhances their readability: s{ / (\d+) / }{ '/' . ($1+1) . '/'}egx

Answer (score 2):

this works:  (`e` is to evaluate the replacement string: see the [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) documentation).

```
$line = '8/10/2010';
$line =~ s!/(\d+)/!('/'.($1+1).'/')!e;

print $line;
```

It helps to use `!` or some other character as the delimiter if your regular expression has `/` itself.

---

You can also use, from this question in [Can Perl string interpolation perform any expression evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939919/can-perl-string-interpolation-perform-any-expression-evaluation)

```
$line = '8/10/2010';
$line =~ s!/(\d+)/!("/@{[$1+1]}/")!e;

print $line;
```

but if this is a homework question, be ready to explain when the teacher asks you how you reach this solution.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about the delimiter character!

Comment: oh no no!, not a homework question, I'll explain it to you - my solution worked but am wondering if there's a better approach.

I'm creating a database of tracking all the users who have used an application. The authentication system is external - however it writes a separate file for each login.

I am trying to get the login-time by capturing the file-creation time and insert in SQL Server DATETIME format.

My first perl program that I wrote missed this important fact - so most of the dates were in 0/0/2010 format(Incompatible with DATETIME). running Perl program again with changes was costly

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$ cat date.txt 
9/0/2010
9/2/2010
10/11/2010
$ perl chdate.pl 
9/1/2010
9/3/2010
10/12/2010
$ cat chdate.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fp, '<', "date.txt" or die $!;

while (<$fp>) {
    chomp;
    my @arr = split (/\//, $_);
    my $temp = $arr[1]+1;
    print "$arr[0]/$temp/$arr[2]\n";
}

close $fp;
$
```

Comment: thanks for this approach - I will keep exploring perl - I have accepted another answer as it solves with a single line

Comment: Yes, those answers are definitely better, I did not know about expressions either.