# Can Perl string interpolation perform any expression evaluation?

Tags: perl, string-interpolation

related to question: [How do I substitute with an evaluated expression in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939788/perl-regex-substituion/3939854)

In Perl, is there a way like in Ruby to do:

```
$a = 1;
print "#{$a + 1}";
```

and it can print out `2`?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There's a similar shorthand in Perl for this:

```
$a = 1;
print "@{[$a + 1]}"
```

This works because the `[]` creates a reference to an array containing one element (the result of the calculation), and then the `@{}` dereferences the array, which inside string interpolation prints each element of the array in sequence. Since there is only one, it just prints the one element.

Comment: There is another option `"${\\($a+1)}"` but I prefer former for readability sake.

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the backslash. I tried this and it works: `"${\($a+1)}"`

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil `print "${\\(Cwd::cwd)}";`get`SCALAR(0x28b7124)`,`print "${\(Cwd::cwd)}";`get`C:/Users/Administrator/IdeaProjects/untitled2` for me

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: You'd mind explaining *why* this works?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `@{[ EXPRESSION ]}` trick that Greg Hewgill mentioned.

There's also the [Interpolation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Interpolation) module, which allows you to do arbitrary transformations on the values you're interpolating (like encode HTML entities) in addition to evaluating expressions.