# call subroutine in print function

Tags: perl

I've got a subroutine: `calcPercentage`. I want to print the value returned by this subroutine.

Can I do this in a single line, similar to this:

```
print "Result is: $calcPercentage($a,$b)"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure: `print "Result is: ", calcPercentage($a, $b), "\n";`

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to pass the function call as one of the arguments to `print`, as the other answers say.

But if, for some reason, you want the result of a function call to be expanded inside a string literal, as `"foo $bar"` expands a variable name, there actually is a (rather ugly) way to do it:

```
print "Result is: @{[calcPercentage($a,$b)]}";
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939919/can-perl-string-interpolation-perform-any-expression-evaluation).

Again, this is not particularly useful if you're just using `print`, since `print` itself concatenates its arguments.  And even if you're not using `print` it's probably better just to concatenate the arguments yourself:

```
$s = "Result is: " . calcPercentage($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do this using a `printf`:

```
printf "Result is: %.2f\n", calcPercentage($a, $b)
```

---

Unrelatedly on a stylistic note, the usual naming convention in perl is `under_scores` not `camelCase`, and `$a` and `$b` are reserved variable names; usually in examples it's better to use `$x` and `$y` which are free.

Answer (score -1):

```
> cat hello.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub hello_p
{

return "hello"
}

print "return value is ",hello_p,"\n";
```

execution is below:

```
> perl hello.pl
return value is hello
```