# How do I use a perl variable name properly within backticks?

Tags: perl, variables, backticks

I need to execute the following code on a bash shell:

```
mogrify -resize 800x600 *JPG
```

Since the width and height are variables, I tried this:

```
`mogrify -resize $widx$hit *JPG`
```

However in compilation, I get the error that `Global symbol "$widx" requires explicit package name at getattach.pl line 131.`, which is because instead of $wid and x seperately, the compiler sees $widx as a new undeclared variable.

I tried inserting double quotes inside the backticks, but execution of code stopped without any messages.

What's the proper way of inserting variable names in backticks for shell execution? Can they be concatenated?

Comment: And not expression in interpolation without hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939919/can-perl-string-interpolation-perform-any-expression-evaluation, only variables.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To insert a variable into any interpolating string (be it `qq//` or `qx` or `qr//`), just doing `"this is $foo!"` is sufficient: The variable name (here: `$foo`) is delimited by the `!` which cannot be part of a normal variable name.

It is not so easy when parts of the string could be part of the name by Perl's naming rules. Example:

```
my $genes = "ACTG$insert_genes_hereACTG";
```

Perl considers the variable name to be `$insert_genes_hereACTG`. This can be solved by

1. Using curlies to delimit the name:

   ```
   my $genes = "ACTG${insert_genes_here}ACTG";
   ```

   This always works and is a flexible solution
2. Concatenating the string:

   ```
   my $genes = "ACTG" . $insert_genes_here . "ACTG";
   ```

   This is a bit difficult for non-`qq`-quotes. A solution is to create a temporary variable that holds the whole string, and then interpolates it into special quotes:

   ```
   my $command = "mogrify -resize " . $wid . "x" . $hit. " *JPG";
   `$command`;
   ```

   A variant of this is to use `sprintf` interpolation:

   ```
   my $command = sprintf 'mogrify -resize %dx%d *JPG', $wid, $hit;
   ```

As an aside, many shell interpolation problems can be circumvented by *not* using backticks, and using `open` or `system` instead (depending on whether or not you need output).

With `open`:

```
open my $command, "-|", "mogrify", "-resize", $wid . "x" . $hit, glob("*JPG")
  or die ...;

while (<$command>) { do something }
```

This completely circumvents the shell (and rather `exec`s directly), so globbing has to be done manually. The same holds true for `system` with more than one argument.

Answer (score 8):

This problem isn't specific to backticks. The problem can happen whenever you interpolate Perl variables in a string.

```
my $wid = 800;
my $hit = 600;

print "$widx$hit"; # this has the same problem
```

The problem is that the Perl compiler can't know where the variable name ("wid") ends and the fixed bit of the string ("x") starts. So it assumes that it is looking for a variable called `$widx` - which doesn't exist.

The solution is to put the name of the variable in `{ ... }`.

```
my $wid = 800;
my $hit = 600;

print "${wid}x$hit"; # This works
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other good responses, you can also use the [`readpipe`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#readpipe) function, which is equivalent to backticks and the `qx` operator. But like a regular function, you can exercise greater control over how the arguments to it are interpolated.

```
$output = readpipe("mogrify -resize $wid" . "x$hit *.JPG");
$output = readpipe( sprintf "mogrify -resize %dx%d *.JPG", $wid, $hit );
```