# How can I combine two strings and treat the result as the name of a variable?

Tags: perl

How can I combine two strings and treat the result as the name of a variable?

I tried this:

```
my $container0 = "voila";
my $container1 = "ssss"; 
my $container2 = "swat"; 

my $container3 = int rand 2; 

my $ans = '$container'."$container3"; 

print "$ans";
```

But it prints:

```
$container2
```

I want to print:

```
swat
```

(the value of the variable `$container2`). How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you want `eval`, but maybe you don't.

Comment: See [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) for the reasons you absolutely *don't* want to do this.

Comment: I'm just curious, not doing this in production or anything. Just for learning purpose, I want to know. Hmm, perhaps Jonathan Leffler is right, I need to use eval.. maybe. Perhaps there are other ways as well. I haven't been this stuck in a while. So really in the exploring mode.

Comment: If you read the link you were given you'll learn that the feature you're probably looking for is a hash or array.

Comment: There is no good reason for learning how to do this. Use a hash. It covers 99.999% of all use cases where you think you'll need this. The other 0.001% I'd consider bad design.

Comment: ofcourse I know how to use an array/hash etc. As I said, I'm just curious to learn a bit more.

Comment: `print $$ans;` without `strict refs` to point the gun directly at your foot.

Comment: somehow that didn't work.. blank printed. Though the script is compiling. still waiting to make this foot bleed :P

Comment: This is also addressed in [perlfaq7: How can I use a variable as a variable name?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name%3f)

Comment: I did :

`our $ans = 'container'."$container3";`
`print $$ans;` 

still blank :/

Comment: interestingly, neither the method listed on perlfaq worked. Is it perhaps because my version is 5.10.1 ?

Comment: You also need to do `our $container0 = ...`;

Comment: Got it! Thanks that was the missing part. If its not much, can you explain, why it works using `ours` and not `my` @Sobrique

Comment: It's to do with scope - by doing a symbolic reference, perl has no 'search context' so uses the global scope - figuring out at run time where to look. (where in normal operation - the name of the variable is irrelevant, and perl can replace it with a memory address).

Comment: seems I learned something interesting after all :) (salute)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off - as the comments say read this: 
http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

The way to do this is with a hash.

```
my %stuff;

$stuff{'container0'} = "voila";
$stuff{'container1'} = "ssss"; 
$stuff{'container2'} = "swat";

my $value = int rand 3;

my $ans = $stuff{'container'.$value};
print $ans,"\n";
```

(Needs to be `3` - `int rand 2` will only ever give you 1 or 0).

However, that's perhaps a bit more complicated than you need.

Instead:

```
my @container = qw ( voila ssss swat );
print $container[rand @container],"\n";
```

For the sake of completeness - here is how you can do it:

**YOU SHOULD NEVER EVER DO THIS, IT IS A TERRIBLE IDEA! IT WILL BREAK YOUR CODE IN ALL SORTS OF OBSCURE WAYS AND IS ENTIRELY REDUNDANT WHEN YOU HAVE HASHES**

```
$container0 = "voila";
$container1 = "ssss"; 
$container2 = "swat"; 

$container3 = int rand 3; 

$ans = 'container'."$container3"; 

print $$ans,"\n";
```

This will give you errors under `strict` and `warnings`.

```
Can't use string ("container1") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use
```

There is a good reason that it does this. I seriously, cannot re-iterate enough how terrible an idea it is to do this when you've perfectly good hashes available. There are all sorts of incredibly funky ways that clobbering random variables in your code can go disastrously wrong. Seriously - read the link above. It has some lovely examples. The best being if you accidentally tamper with some of the `special` variables, such as `$*` or `$/` and screw up every regular expression or filehandle in the rest of your program - you'll be looking in the wrong place for the source of the error.

Edit: To follow on from a comment - you cannot use `my` if you do this - you need to use `our`. The easiest way to understand why, is just imagine that `my` renames a variable to a function unique name, and 'hides' it from the rest of the package. Because the symbolic ref evaluates at *run* time - perl can't pre-prepare when it's doing it's compilation and validation phases, so cannot 'see' the lexically scoped variable when it's running.

Using `our` would declare the variable in a broader scope (e.g. effectively global). So like this: (But it's still nasty)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

no strict "refs"; 

our $container0 = "voila";
our $container1 = "ssss"; 
our $container2 = "swat"; 

my $container3 = int rand 3; 

my $ans = 'container'."$container3"; 

print $$ans,"\n";
```

Also refer to the FAQ for some more reasons it's not a good idea:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name%3f

Comment: Thanks man, but I know how to do it using a hash or otherwise. Just out of curiosity, I want to know if its possible to interpret in strictly scalar sense.

Comment: Perl is a very flexible language. It's very possible. But not if you use `strict` and `warnings`, because it's a horrifically bad idea. People aren't wanting to tell you, because there's NO good reasons to do it. 

However, for the sake of completeness - I'll edit the answer.

Comment: yes, I can understand what you are trying to say. I will accept your answer for now, and also upvote others who helped out. But as it is, I'm still getting a blank output here. I'm guessing it might be due to my perl version being 5.10.1 or something. Or just because this method is so rudimentary. 

Should I just accept your answer, and upvote others, as a thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: THanks a lot man, if only you could edit the answer above, and add.. a small explanation, why it works with `ours` instead of `my`, I would be very thankful for the extra effort.

Comment: I think there's a slight bug in the code, it should be: $ans = 'container'."$container3"; # no '$'
then it works.  This is under the condition that the variables are not lexically scoped (no "my" as in the original question).

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with terminology here, where the term "interpret" is used:

- What double-quotes do is called "[interpolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Perl)".  You can read about it here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators.  This mostly supports some escape sequences and variable substitution.
- If you are looking to print "swat" in the case of $container2, then that's called "[evaluate](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)".  This treats the string as Perl code.  To confuse things further, there is a way to evaluate an expression within an interpolated string: [Can Perl string interpolation perform any expression evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939919/can-perl-string-interpolation-perform-any-expression-evaluation).

In answer to your question, you can use:

```
print eval ( $ans );
```

or

```
print "@{[ eval ( $ans ) ]}";
```

There is a good summary of all this here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=408346, and it also suggests using [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Interpolate/) as yet another solution.

Comment: nope, even after using eval, it is still printing: container1

Thanks for the clarification about the terminology. I hardly went through the theory, dived head in first.

Comment: <shrug> I tested it myself, and it prints "swat".

Comment: could it be due to difference in perl versions? I'm using 5.10.1

Comment: I'm getting the same result under 5.10.0.

Comment: Yet another mystery worth solving, but not tonight. Gotta sleep. Thanks a lot Arnon!

Comment: Difference is the contents of $ans. `my  $ans = '$container'."$container3"; print eval ( $ans );`. Where above, for `$$` you need to omit the `$` prefix, when doing `eval` you need to include it.