# using variables to specify other variables

Tags: perl, variables

Can you use a stored variable, say from pattern match (`$1`, `$2`...), to specify another variable to push a value to?  Here is a bit of code to help explain my question:

```
my @Array_some;
while (<SOMEFILE>){
    if ($_ =~ /(some)(match)/) {
        push (@Array_$1, $2);
    }
}
```

When I run this I get an error:

> `Scalar found where operator expected near "@Array_$1"`

From this I conclude that this type of syntax is not possible.  However, is what I was going for possible, but in another way?  Using a pattern-matched variable to specify another variable to push values to?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I will offer my previous reply on this subject: Perl is very flexible, and you _can_ do this. There are NO good reasons to do so - so `use strict;` will prevent you. Use a hash. For more detail - my previous answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473593/interpreting-a-string-inside-a-string-perl/26473857#26473857

Answer (score 3):

What you're attempting to do is [ill-advised](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

Instead, just use a Hash of Arrays, like so:

```
my %HoA;

while (<SOMEFILE>){
    if (/(some)(match)/) {
        push @{ $HoA{$1} }, $2;
    }
    ...;
```

For more info on complex structures, check out [perldsc - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: Do we have a canonical question on this subject yet? Seems like something that probably should be.

Comment: Not one that I'm aware of, but I'm fine using yours for now.  Most of the time I think this is answered rather quickly though, and there are enough variations that a certain level of hand holding is ok.